# VBA absolute macro taking forver

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make a select column of cells all be positive. I created this macro and it is working....just taking awhile. It's been running for probably 5min now. Mind you I do have 200k rows of data for it to search through...Anyone else have this problem before or ideas for it to be faster for next time???

```
Sub Positive()
Dim Cel As Range
For Each Cel In Selection 
If IsNumeric(Cel.Value) Then
Cel.Value = Abs(Cel.Value)
End If
Next Cel 
End Sub
```

Comment: `Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For ...
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True`
Might speed it up a bit

Comment: What is your Selection ? If it's the whole worksheet remember it's 
1,048,576 rows by 16,384 columns (billions of operations). Limit your selection and it will be much more faster

Comment: Try [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You can turn off calculations: `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` before entering the loop and `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` after exiting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give this a try and let me know how the performance is:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Positive()

Dim varArray As Variant
Dim lngRow As Long, lngColumn As Long

varArray = Selection.Value2
For lngRow = LBound(varArray, 1) To UBound(varArray, 1)
    For lngColumn = LBound(varArray, 2) To UBound(varArray, 2)
        If IsNumeric(varArray(lngRow, lngColumn)) Then
            varArray(lngRow, lngColumn) = Abs(varArray(lngRow, lngColumn))
        End If
    Next lngColumn
Next lngRow
Selection.Value2 = varArray

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can save the range to an array, then process the array and write it back to the range, not tested but should be close.

```
Dim myArr() As Variant
myArr = Range("A1:A10")
Dim iCount As Long
For iCount = LBound(myArr) To UBound(myArr)
   myArr(iCount) = abs(myArr(iCount))
Next iCount
Range("A1:A10") = myArr
```

Comment: It seems we had the same idea.

Comment: @Ralph I should have been quicker!